# print html form including image

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm tying to make html print function but the image which already defined and shown in the aspx form does not exist in the html print form

the image is included in QuotePanel

this is the image definition from the aspx form

```
 <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="70px" 
                ImageUrl="~/abc.jpg" Width="700px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and this is the code behind

```
public static void PrintWebControl(Control ControlToPrint)
{
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    if (ControlToPrint is WebControl)
    {
        Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage);
        ((WebControl)ControlToPrint).Width = w;
    }
    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    frm.Controls.Add(ControlToPrint);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ctrl"] = QuotePanel;
   QuotePanel.Visible = true;
   Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
   PrintWebControl(ctrl);


}
```

Comment: Does the text in the form print? (i.e. can you narrow this down specifically to the image that is the issue?)

what happens if you just do Window.Print() on the client side rather than doing a postback?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make of your code, you are trying to get the page to print using a postback that then runs javascript to get the client to perform the print.

It would be much simpler if you modified your print button to not do a postback (remove "runat=server" and change the type to a simple HTML button) and set the onclick event to perform the window.print().  This would not only simplify the code, but also make it perform better, since it would not need to do a round-trip to the server to print the page.